# I am facing problem in npm install express --save

Tags: node.js, npm

I am new to nodejs and while trying to install express using command `npm install express --save`, it showed the following error-

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...NS32nytG/grOSzaMcv/L3'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Upwn\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-06-05T03_36_28_496Z-debug.log

Comment: try updating node and npm once . make sure to use latest version. Or try reinstalling node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue. Try`npm cache clean --force`. and then run `npm install express --save`.It solved my issue.